# How can I breed a Panlong Dragon

Tags: dragonvale

I want to breed a Panlong Dragon. Which dragons should I breed and how will I know whether I got one? How long are they available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can breed any two hybrid dragons that collectively have all four elements **Fire, Earth, Water and Air**.

Example breeding pairs are **Mud + Blaze** or Lava + Fog. In fact those are the only breeding pairs not counting rares. Note the dragon is **rare** and will take several tries; you might want to use the Epic Breeding Island.

Panlong Dragons have a unique breeding/egg time of **36 hours** so you'll know when you got one right away; they also have a unique egg.

Panlong Dragons will be [**available for the entire of the Year of the Dragon**](https://twitter.com/#!/backflipstudios/status/161858867049934849) (2012). If you have at least two you'll be able to breed Panlong dragons together to get Panlongs even after the event is over.

Answer (score 1):

I bred my first Panlong dragon on the Epic Breeding Island. First try did not work but the second time did and I'm breeding another one right now. Both dragons are on lvl 10 lava (left) + fog (right).

Tried it on the normal breeding cave several times and it never worked, finally gave up and bought an Epic Breeding Island. It's worth it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Lava left and fog right - worked on the 2nd try.

Answer (score 1):

A dodo and an air creates a panglong.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried Lava and Fog and got another Rainbow.